# Shared Primary Key for multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, primary-key

So I have 3 tables:

Pokemon:

```
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| National_ID   | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Picture       | longblob    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Name          | varchar(15) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Generation_ID | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Type1         | varchar(8)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Type2         | varchar(8)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Stats:

```
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| National_ID     | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Health_Points   | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Attack          | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Defense         | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Special_Attack  | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Special_Defense | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Speed           | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Ability1        | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Ability2        | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Misc:

```
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| National_ID  | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Evolves_From | varchar(15) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Species      | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Height_inch  | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Weight_lbs   | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Capture_Rate | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

My problem is that the National_ID in the Stats table points to the National_ID in the Pokemon table, but I cannot do the same for the Misc table.

Whenever I try to add a foreign key in Misc to point to the Pokemon table, I get a duplication error.  Help please! Thank you

Comment: Does Misc table have any foreign key constraint on it?

Comment: No, after this query "ALTER TABLE Misc ADD CONSTRAINT FK_National_ID FOREIGN KEY (National_ID) REFERENCES Pokemon(National_ID);"  I would receive a duplication error.

Comment: Please specify how you want the tables to relate to each other. Forget 'foreign keys' etc. Just explain how you want the tables to relate to each other. Using the current colums would be useful

Comment: I want each table to have the same National_ID

Comment: @BerryAllen If it says its a duplication error, you probably have the same constraint name. Have you tried a different name?

Comment: If I change the constraint name, will it still point to the National_ID from the Pokemon table?

Comment: @BerryAllen Yes, the relationship is not determined by the name but instead by the column names mentioned in the foreign key and references part of the syntax. Name is just an identifier. It own its own doesn't define the relationship.

Comment: "I want each table to have the same National_ID" is unintelligible. Please use more words. Explain as if we don't know what you are trying to do. Because we don't.

Comment: Please show DDL, exact error messages and any other (minimal) info necessary to reproduce a problem. Please edit your clarifications into your question.

Comment: This looks like a lot fun to program :) If you would just explain it clearly. Not how to do it - but what to do? There should be some explanation of the problem _before your table defintions_ And why you chose those `table structures` as a means of solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, it looks like you already have a foreign key constraint with name `'FK_National_ID'`. Try changing it to `'FK_Pokemon_National_ID'` or something and it should work.

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/578a7/2/0).

Answer (score 0):

Every FOREIGN KEY declaration that a table & list of column names REFERENCES a table & list of column names needs a unique name. (If you don't give one explicitly then the DBMS will make one up.)